# How to use Liquid to get contents of a text file

Tags: shopify, liquid

In Shopify, I have some code that loops through a list of colors and displays them on the page:

```
{% assign colors = "red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet" | split:"," %}
{% for color in colors %}<p>{{ color | capitalize }}</p>{% endfor %}
```

In order to make this as easy as possible for my non-technical client to update the available colors, I'd love to be able to separate out the list in a separate file containing just the list (with no Liquid whatsoever). I tried putting it in a snippet...

### snippets/colors.liquid

```
red,
orange,
yellow,
green,
blue,
indigo,
violet
```

and then changing the 1st line to:

```
{% assign colors = render "colors" | split:"," %}
```

but that gave an error:  `Liquid syntax error: Expected end_of_string but found string in "{{render 'colors' }}"`.

Is there any way to just get the contents of a file and assign it to a String variable?

Comment: Out of curiousity, is there any reason you are using a snippet file instead of a section with settings that can be edited through the 'Customize' option on the theme?

Comment: @DaveB - none that make actual sense. This is how the client is wanting to do it....

Answer (score 1):

`capture` grabs everything between tags as a string and assigns it to the. variable named

```
{%- capture colors -%}
{%- render 'colors' -%}
{% endcapture %}

{% assign all_colors = colors | newline_to_br | split: '<br />' %}
{% for color in all_colors %}<p>{{ color | capitalize }}</p>{% endfor %}
```

### snippets/colors.liquid

```
red
orange
yellow
green
blue
indigo
violet
```

Comment: To avoid empty-string entries at the beginning and end of the array - which would be caused by the line breaks following the 'capture' and preceding the 'endcapture' tags (capture captures everything!), I would recommend using the whitespace-stripping marks: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/whitespace/  (eg: `{% - capture colors -%}`)